# Java enumeration for grades

Tags: java, enums

Good day people,
I have an assignment to write a Java enumeration that represents letter grades A through F.

That if all good, with the following code that I use:

```
A(true), B(true),  C(true), D(true), E(true), F(false);
```

The Boolean value indicates whether the student has passed or failed.

The problem is that we need to include plus and minus grades.  But I don't know how to structure it...A+ etc. doesn't work.

Any advice or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: *A+ etc. doesn't work.* how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you need to provide a boolean for each grade? I mean the grade will be associated with a student for e.g. So class Student will have a property of type Grade which will either be A or B etc. It would not be false of A or True of B, if you are getting me!

Comment: Have a look to my solution below with more explanation of the pattern used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`А+` doesn't work, because the `+` is an operator in Java.

Better add a few more grades, like:

```
A_PLUS(true), A_MINUS(true), .... , F_PLUS(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kocko, answered, you cannot use `A+` as `+` is an operator in java but you can override `toString()` method so that you can give some meaningful representation to enum type.

If you want you could use a string representation like `A+` for enum `A_PLUS` using `toString` method. Learn more about [enumeration in java](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/01/why-use-enumerations-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You will use the **enum pattern**. It works also with the plain class, the Java enum is just a [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

First the **class solution**, so you may compare it.

```
public class Grade {
    final public static Grade A = new Grade(true, "A");
    final public static Grade A_PLUS = new Grade(true, "A+");
    final public static Grade A_MINUS = new Grade(true, "A-");
    ...
    final public static Grade E = new Grade(true, "E");
    final public static Grade F = new Grade(false, "F");

    final private boolean passed;
    final private String name;

    // private constructor - no-one can create any other instance then those above
    private Grade(boolean passed, String name) {
        this.passed = passed;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean hasPassed() {
        return this.passed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then for comparison the **enum solution**. You should understand the **design pattern**. Enum is just more convenient syntax + more reliable serializability, nothing more.

```
public enum Grade {
    A(true),
    A_PLUS(true),
    A_MINUS(true),
    B(true),
    B_PLUS(true),
    ...
    E(true),
    F(false);

    final private boolean passed;

    private Grade(boolean passed) {
        this.passed = passed;
    }

    public boolean hasPassed() {
        return this.passed;
    }

    // Thanks to special bonus functionality of enums, which are aware of their name
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final String name = name();
        if (name.contains("PLUS")) {
            return name.charAt(0) + "+"; 
        }
        else if (name.contains("MINUS")) {
            return name.charAt(0) + "-"; 
        }
        else {
            return name;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

well try to used the class like below 
Note: this is the easy way to access the grade.

```
public class Grade {
    private Long id;
    // this will be the upper case store and read
    private String grade;
}
```